# Move a window to top left corner

Tags: macos, window, applescript

I'm trying to move a window to the top left corner of my screen.

This is what I've written:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "appIT"
        tell window 1
            --Move lobby to left corner
            set s to size
            activate
            set the bounds to {40, 40, item 1 of s, item 2 of s}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

But when I run the script I'm getting this error:

> System Events found an error: I can't set bounds of window 1 of application process "appIT" to {40, 40, 1037, 696}

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working:

```
tell window 1
    activate
    set position to {0, 20}
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it work with something like this:

```
tell application "appIT"
    tell window 1
        --Move lobby to left corner
        set s to bounds
        activate
        set the bounds to {40, 40, (item 3 of s) - (item 1 of s), (item 4 of s) - (item 2 of s)}
    end tell
end tell
```